# How to delete arbitrary objects in repeated field? (protobuf)

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I have some entries in the repeated field in my proto. Now I want delete some of them. How can I accomplish this? There is a function to delete the last element, but I want to delete arbitrary elements. I cant just swap them because the order is important.

I could swap with next until end, but isn't there a nicer solution?

Comment: Maybe I'm too stupid, but can you explain your problem in more detail?  What framework/library are you working with?  Source code?

Comment: The library is protocol buffers (protobuf) from google. I guess I dont need source code here. Repeated fields are dataholders similar to the STL containers.

Comment: for users of protobuf v3, be sure to scroll beyond the accepted answer to here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35837227/10278

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to the [API docs](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.repeated_field#RepeatedField.RemoveLast.details), there isn't a way to arbitrarily remove an element from within a repeated field, just a way to remove the last one.

> ...
>   We don't provide a way to remove any element other than the last
>   because it invites inefficient use, such as O(n^2) filtering loops
>   that should have been O(n). If you want to remove an element other
>   than the last, the best way to do it is to re-arrange the elements so
>   that the one you want removed is at the end, then call RemoveLast()
>   ...

Answer (score 22):

**For Protobuf v3**

[`iterator RepeatedField::erase(const_iterator position)`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.repeated_field#RepeatedField.erase.details) can delete at arbitrary position.

**For Protobuf v2**

You can use the [`DeleteSubrange(int start, int num)`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.repeated_field#RepeatedPtrField.DeleteSubrange.details) in `RepeatedPtrField` class.

If you want to delete a single element then you have to call this method as `DeleteSubrange(index_to_be_del, 1)`. It will remove the element at that index.

Comment: i'm curious, why not just use `erase`: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.repeated_field#RepeatedField.erase.details

Comment: @johnbakers At that time protobuf v3 is not released, `erase` is not in protobuf v2. It is also mentioned in the accepted answer that they didn't provide any method to erase in v2

Comment: I tried DeleteSubrange to delete element from repeated Field but it was not working , i tried for(int var = 0; var < foo.repeatedField_size(); var++)
      {
   foo.mutable_repeated_field()->DeleteSubrange(var,1);

      }

Answer (score 8):

What I usually do in these cases is to create a new Protobuf (PB) message. I iterate the repeated fields of the existing message and add them (except the ones you don't want anymore) to the new PB message.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example:

```
message GuiChild
{
    optional string widgetName = 1;
    //..
}

message GuiLayout
{
    repeated ChildGuiElement children = 1;
    //..
}

typedef google_public::protobuf::RepeatedPtrField<GuiChild> RepeatedField;
typedef google_public::protobuf::Message Msg;

GuiLayout guiLayout; 
//Init children as necessary..

GuiChild child;
//Set child fileds..

DeleteElementsFromRepeatedField(*child, guiLayout->mutable_children());

void DeleteElementsFromRepeatedField(const Msg& msg, RepeatedField* repeatedField)
{
    for (RepeatedField::iterator it = repeatedField->begin(); it != repeatedField->end(); it++)
    {
        if (google_public::protobuf::util::MessageDifferencer::Equals(*it, msg))
        {
            repeatedField->erase(it);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: from https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.repeated_field#RepeatedField.erase.details, it says: "Invalidates all iterators at or after the removed element, including end()", so I think the `it++` is invalid

Answer (score 0):

Although there's no straight-forward method you still can do this (for custom message using reflection). Code below removes `count` repeated field items starting from `row` index.

```
void RemoveFromRepeatedField(
    const google::protobuf::Reflection *reflection,
    const google::protobuf::FieldDescriptor *field,
    google::protobuf::Message *message,
    int row,
    int count)
{
    int size = reflection->FieldSize(*message, field);
    // shift all remaining elements
    for (int i = row; i < size - count; ++i)
        reflection->SwapElements(message, field, i, i + count);
    // delete elements from reflection
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        reflection->RemoveLast(message, field);
}
```