# Delete a random value from repeated string ( list ) in Google Protocol buffer

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I want to delete an item from repeated field

For say we have a message defination:

```
message foo {
repeated string temp1 ; 
repeated string temp2 ; 
}
```

I want to remove item from temp1 at some random index;

As per my knowledge I can delete by swapping the last element and using RemoveLast; 
But I dont know how to use that. Any help with code snapshot in c++ ?

Comment: What language is this? It's surely not C++! If this is some IDL that protobuf creates C++ code from, you need to look at that code to figure out how to work with it. Concerning the removal of elements from a container, use any C++ tutorial to get familiar with containers.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt It is google protobuf definition. C++ class is generated out of this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete arbitrary objects in repeated field? (protobuf)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13603878/how-to-delete-arbitrary-objects-in-repeated-field-protobuf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one [reason](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/protobuf/OveVcOemyBA) why there is no `Remove()` in the `protocol buffer`.

> I didn't want to provide a `Remove(int)` because it would be `O(n)`.  *Version 1* of protocol buffers had such a function, and we frequently saw people writing loops like:
>
> ```
>  for (int i = 0; i < field.size(); i++) {
>   if (ShouldFilter(field[i])) {
>     field.Remove(i);
>     --i;
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> This loop is `O(n^2)`, which is bad, but it's hard to tell that it is `O(n^2)`.  The idea behind only providing `RemoveLast()` is to force you to either do something clever (like swapping the element with the last element first, as the documentation suggests) or write your own loop which makes the time complexity of your code obvious.

Two options are here:

- Copy the item from the end of the list into the space formerly occupied by the item you want to delete, then call `RemoveLast()`.
- By using `iterator erase(const_iterator position)`, but you should start from `begin()`, then to check whether the value of this iterator should be removed.